# Sound Problems ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: sound

I have a little problem with Ubuntu... After I updated the kernel to 3.14.1-031401-generic, my sound has stopped working. At first, I only had sound out of the left speaker but not the right. However, after the update, I don't have any sound! Thank you for your time!

Note: Before I did update, I did have sound out of the left speaker. My headset is the Razer Kraken non-usb. Should I try to roll back the kernel?

Side Note: I later noticed that I needed to install unity control panel. Speakers now work! I did both what you said and the control panel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following command from terminal

```
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

And then restart. This should be enough to fix it. If not you may need to reinstall

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And then reinstall

```
 sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And then run

```
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

**Side Note**
I suspect the force reload will fix, just be sure to restart after. You shouldn't need to reinstall, but I included just in case.

I just had this problem with no sound all of a sudden and

```
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

Fixed it for me. Hope helps.

Edit: Now that I think of it, since you had problems to begin with (only one speaker working) you may need to do a reinstall, but I would definitely try force-reload first.